# Economic damage of (single pieces) of plastic

Tags: environmental-economics

I want to know the impact of individual plastic items on everything (us, animals, the Earth...) all converted into money. For example, this bottle generally brings about a damage of x dollars, that one-use cutlery costs the environment y dollars... That would be easier to form a visceral image of our impact instead of the big numbers of total damage.

Comment: I think you mean a specific type of bottle rather than this specific bottle.

Comment: ah yes, my bad.